# how to switch to console on a vmware guest?

Tags: vmware-player

I can see the console of a vmware guest machine, but I cannot switch to the non-GUI console of it.

I can only see the GUI login for the redhat linux guest.

If I press CTRL+ALT+F2, my hosts machine will switch to console, not the guest.

If I press the CTRL+ALT+SPACE, then release the space, but still pressing CTRL+ALT then F2, again, my hosts machine will switch to console.

Comment: I guessed it is [vmware-player], if it is [vmware-workstation] then please correct.